При запуске из файла main.py не видит базу данных peewee в пакетах
Пишу бота для домашнего задания по курсу обучения.
Помогите, пожалуйста, мучаюсь с подключением к базе данных:
Ошибка: нет доступа "peewee.OperationalError: unable to open database file"
При запуске файла main выдается эта ошибка. При этом, если из файла, на который и указывает ошибка, запустить код, то всё хорошо. Пакеты связаны следующим образом:

В main.py у меня импортированы хендлеры (откуда идёт вызов) и функция создания модели (но судя по всему она не особо нужна, т.к. и без неё из пакета запуск происходил и норм отрабатывал)
Из пакета хендлеров при смене состояния идёт обращение к функции поиска станции в БД, которая находится в другом пакете
Эта функция поиска и обращается к пакету с ORM и БД. Только таким "коленом" не видит. Только если напрямую запускать из пакета с функцией поиска или из любых других пакетов.

Может я накосячил в venv, но я не понимаю, что с ним сделать. Внутри него вообще нет загруженных модулей (типа peewee или telebot), но они работают.


Большое спасибо!

Ошибка в адресе расположения базы данных в конфигурационном файле (т.к. обращение идёт уже из main, который в корне проекта, путь скорректировал из тестового формата в рабочий).
